# API reference: Where to find all the properties available for aggregation binding info object?

Tags: sapui5

Where can I find aggregation binding properties like `path`, `factory`, etc.. in the API reference?

Just like in following code

```xml
<List items="{
  path: '/Products',
  factory: '.productListFactory',
  ...
}">
```

Where to find more such properties and their descriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see more such properties in [`ManagedObject#bindAggregation`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/methods/bindAggregation).

Additionally, `parameters` and `events` await key-value pairs of which the possible keys are documented in the corresponding model type.

For example, the keys for `parameters`, when binding with a `v2.ODataModel`, can be found in [`ODataModel#bindList`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/bindList) or in [`ODataListBinding`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataListBinding). The latter module also documents which `events` can be registered. *

```js
{ // Standard options. See ManagedObject bindAggregation
  path: '...',
  filters: [/*...*/],
  ...
  parameters: { // Model dependent. See e.g. ODataListBinding constructor
    expand: 'ToA, ToB/ToB1/ToB2, ToC',
    select: 'ProductID, ProductName',
    custom: { 'myquery': '...' },
    batchGroupId: 'myGroup',
  },
  events: { // Model dependent. See e.g. ODataListBinding events
    dataRequested: '.onDataRequested',
    dataRequested: '.onDataReceived',
    change: '.onDataChange'
  }
}
```

---

* Enhanced the API reference accordingly in [OpenUI5 commit `8311dd3`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/8311dd3ecf5375d0f51cf5ebd8d04f602dfb0f6c).

Answer (score 1):

That's a binding (they're enclosed in {}).

You can use the [getBindingInfo method](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/methods/getBindingInfo).

So, for example, if your List control has the id "mylist":

```
this.getView().byId("mylist").getBindingInfo("items");
```

It will return you an object containing all the binding properties, such as path and factory.